# git pull is slow when used in ant script

Tags: git, ant

So, here is the deal:

```
    matthijs@xx:xx (master)$ ant -v update
Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on January 6 2007
Buildfile: build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85.x86_64/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /var/www/xx/xx/xx/build.xml with URI = file:///var/www/xx/xx/xx/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /var/www/xx/xx/xx
Build sequence for target(s) `update' is [git-pull, update]
Complete build sequence is [git-pull, update, composer-master, master_check, fetch_master, lint, api_check, create_api, prune_api, fetch_api, use_api, create_master, prune_master, use_master, shared_check, create_shared, prune_shared, fetch_shared, use_shared, webservices_check, create_webservices, prune_webservices, fetch_webservices, use_webservices, use_dependencies, clean, prepare, basedir, composer-api, composer-portal, copy_api_ini, copy_portal_ini, phpdoc, build_nocq, phpunit, build_and_test, code-coverage, phpcpd, commit, pdepend, full_build, phpcs, pdepend-w-charts, ]

git-pull:
     [echo] git pull
     [exec] Current OS is Linux
     [exec] Executing 'git' with arguments:
     [exec] 'pull'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Username for 'https://git.xx.net': matthijs
Password for 'https://matthijs@git.xx.net':
     [exec] Already up-to-date.

update:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 32 seconds
```

As you can see it takes 30+ seconds to complete.

The (related) stuff from my build.xml file:

```
  <macrodef name = "git">
    <attribute name = "command" />
    <!--<attribute name = "options" default=""/>-->
    <attribute name = "dir" default = "" />
    <element name = "args" optional = "true" />
    <sequential>
      <echo message = "git @{command}" />
      <exec executable = "git" dir = "@{dir}">
        <arg value = "@{command}" />
        <!--<arg value = "@{options}" />-->
        <args/>
      </exec>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <target name="git-pull" description="Pull the current git branch">
    <git command="pull" dir="." />
  </target>

  <target name="update" depends="git-pull" />
```

(Removed all non relevant code)

When I execute a `git pull` through CLI it is way faster:

```
matthijs@xx:xx (master)$ time git pull
Username for 'https://git.xx.net': matthijs
Password for 'https://matthijs@git.xx.net':
Already up-to-date.

real    0m2.997s
user    0m0.081s
sys     0m0.083s
```

Why is the 'direct' way so much faster? Does ant doe more things? Does it not know when git is 'done'?

Note without password (password cached) it is quick. Yes I know it is possible to use ssh keys etc but this should not be needed.

edit:
Really strange, this is with password cached (that was quick just a few moments ago)

```
matthijs@xx:xx (master)$ ant update
Buildfile: build.xml

git-pull:
     [echo] git pull
     [exec] Already up-to-date.

update:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 13 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your ant version, as 1.6.5 is rather old.
You may try the [JGit based ant tasks](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks) (get binaries [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit)), to see if they work better with ant/java.